# Error al firmar documentos en Adobe Reader

Tags: firma-digital, certificado

Tengo un problema cuando intento firmar un documento pdf con Adobe Reader. Me aparece el error que adjunto en la imagen.
He probado con otros certificados para comprobar que no sea el certificado y tampoco funcionan. También he probado el certificado en otro equipo y funciona perfectamente.

También he probado a desinstalar por completo Adobe Reader y volverlo a instalar en la última versión y tampoco ha dado resultado.

El sistema es Windows Server 2012 R2 virtualizado en un ESXI 6.7
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]